# How to efficiently POST binary data from node.js to PHP

Tags: php, node.js, http, post

I'm using Node.js to send binary data to PHP. The POST data contains a JSON string, followed by newline, then the binary part.

Sending data from Node:

```
let binary = null;
if('binary' in msg)
{
    binary = msg.binary;
    delete msg.binary;
}
let buf = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(msg) + (binary === null ? '' : '\n'));
if(binary !== null) buf = Buffer.concat([buf, binary]);
let response = await axios.post
(
    url,
    buf
);
```

...and receiving it in PHP:

```
$binary = null;
$in = file_get_contents('php://input');
$pos = strpos($in, "\n");
if($pos === false)
{
    $_POST = json_decode($in, true);
}
else
{
    $_POST = json_decode(substr($in, 0, $pos), true);
    $binary = substr($in, $pos + 1);
}
```

This works, but I'm getting a warning:

PHP Warning:  Unknown: Input variables exceeded 1000.

Is there any way to prevent PHP from trying to parse the POST data?

Comment: Would a blob help you? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob

Comment: How big is the data packet? You might just base64 encode it.

Comment: @AlexHowansky I'm trying to avoid base 64. The data is up to 0.5MiB per request.

Comment: @SimonK It's the receiving end I'm having trouble with.

Comment: You're sending a JSON packet with a binary blob just pasted to the end? If your JSON packet contains a newline anywhere in it, the decode will break. Just encode the blob as text and embed it in the JSON. What's the problem with base64? If you're concerned about space, gzip it first, then b64, it's like two functions calls, done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate file from json:

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', fs.createReadStream(filepath));
formData.append('json', '{"jsonstring":"values"}');
axios.post(url, formData, {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
    },
  }).then((response) => {
    fnSuccess(response);
  }).catch((error) => {
    fnFail(error);
  });
```

And PHP

```
$jsonstring  = $_POST['json'];
$json = json_decode($jsonstring,true); // array

$uploaddir = "path/to/uploads/";
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile))
{
  $uploadfile // is the path to file uploaded
}
```

Comment: In order to prevent 'Missing boundary in multipart/form-data', use `headers: formData.getHeaders()` instead of `headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" }`

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered PUT. It does exactly what I'm looking for. Just have to change

`axios.post(url, buf)`

to

`axios.put(url, buf)`

On the PHP side, there's no attempt to decode anything - it is up to the script to interpret the data.

Although this allows me to do what I want, using it this way violates the [HTTP specification](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.0/spec.html#PUT). In my case that's not a big deal because it is being used internally, and it prevents some of PHP's unnecessary (for this situation) pre-processing and file I/O.